# Can't upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 due to low disk space in /

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, apt

I am unable to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 because of low disk space in my root `/` partition. Any help? I already have a 6 GB drive mounted on /. I do not understand why there is a memory issue.

Comment: 6GB is fairly small, especially if you have a lot of media files in your `/home` folder.  Check your `/home` folder for media files and check the '/boot' folder for old, unused kernels.

Comment: Memory or Hard Drive space?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. 6GB is not a particularly large amount of space for a Ubuntu install. It will depend what you already have in other folders. If you could post the result of the below from the terminal (use `Ctrl-Alt-T` to start it):

`df -h`

We may be able to help you more.

Also try `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean` to remove old/unneeded packages and then run `df -h` again.

Bill

Answer (score 0):

The new packages are downloaded in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`, so just create a symbolic link to a different location (another hard drive or partition). This solved the problem for me.